# Edits that "fix" or "improve" an answer

Tags: discussion, answers, suggested-edits

From time to time I see an edit that tries to fix or improve the answer. For instance, this one adds all the required includes for answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5776165

This one adds more resolutions to the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5776055

I've generally rejected these edits because we don't know if this is what the answerer had in mind or if these edits fix or cause more issues. Generally, IMO, these edits are really comments or can be combined to create a new answer. Am I being harsh in rejecting edits like these?

Edit: I tend to see most people accepting these edits.

Comment: The first edit is misleading; the diff is not accurate as the [post was edited to remove the code the suggested edit **appears** to add](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25852826/revisions). In other words, the editor did not themselves add those includes.

Comment: The second edit applies changes *already mentioned in the comments*. The anon user there is actually being helpful.

Comment: The first edit was rejected (correctly so, the edit is outdated), the second is an edit that is quite acceptable.

Comment: Now that suggested edit reviews are checked out (e.g. you get to review exclusively without anyone else voting it through or out from underneath you), you should really take the time to investigate the context on these edits. If something looks like a weird edit, look at the post comments and the revision history before approving or declining.

Comment: @MartijnPieters bad thing about second edit is that [summary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/edit-summary/info) doesn't mention that it is copied from comments - as a result, reviewers may be mislead that "Updated with the latest density values" is totally idea of the user who suggested an edit

Comment: @MartijnPieters however, the difficulty is generally we don't see the comments in the review page. Also it wasn't added by the answerer, so there's always the fear that it taints the answer (if incorrect additions are made?). I'm an Android developer so I can understand the edit and it seems valid, however, if I wasn't, how can I be certain it's an accurate edit?

Comment: @gnat: sure, a proper editing summary would have helped there.

Comment: @ajacian81: when unsure, there is the option to *skip the review*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok thanks. So in general, if an edit actually provides additional code that appears to improve an answer, we should accept it?

Comment: I don't agree with @MartijnPieters. If someone does an edit to include things from a comment, I think the very least we can expect from them is to mention this in the edit reason, for example "Including code from comments". We are asking too much of the reviewers if they have to manually open each post with an edit of this nature and read through all the comments. Which we would have to, as comments aren't visible in the edit review itself.

Comment: @Lundin: I did state that a proper summary would have helped. It was an *anonymous user* that made the edit, at which point you need to look closely anyway as it'll be someone unfamiliar with how we handle things on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I also don't agree with @MartijnPieters  based on the assumption that it's the role of a reviewer to ensure the accuracy/validity of technical/code edits. What happens if there are no reviewers who are subject matter experts in a field for which a technical edit (e.g. correction) is made? Does that mean that such an edit would never be approved?

Comment: @CJBS: note that the OP has a veto vote. It could be that the edit would never be declined or approved if no experts step up. I don't think that's really a problem however.

Answer (score 4):

In these cases I usually take a look at the whole post seeking for comments that may have generated those edits, as general practice. I do so in order to avoid rejecting a valid edit.

Now, adding missing *includes* makes sense as long as:

- They are **substantial** to understand the problem.
- Posted code is intended to be a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so *includes* are relevant to run the example.

On the other hand, assuming a wrong include may lead to misunderstanding and waste of time. For example, in Java world there are two classes called Timer: [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) both intended to be used in a different way. It is pretty a common issue that questioner has been using the wrong import without stating this fact. If someone assumes that he was using the right include and mistakenly edits the question, then other people may overlook the source of the problem.

Now, about the second suggested edit it is ok for me because those details were extracted from the link that is the answer's basis. In fact this is a really good improvement because it makes the *best dimensions for the app to run in all devices* be on-site.